# Return result from PL/pgSQL without function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'd like to run SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE AND DELETE data on PL/pgSQL without using function, what code should i try?

I've tried this to do the SELECT one:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
PERFORM * FROM employees;
END; $$
```

the query can be run, but it shows nothing on the data output.

Comment: Try to use SELECT instead PERFORM: `SELECT * FROM employees;`

Comment: i have to do it in PL/pgSQL form

Comment: I think what Slava said is accurate - Please see reference for PostgreSQL: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_select_query.htm

Comment: `do` blocks can not return a result. If you want to return a result and don't want to use a plain SELECT statement a function is the **only** option you have. What's wrong with using a simple SELECT? What is the **real** underlying problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: The above is a function, it is just an anonymous one.  As stated above ```DO``` cannot return anything.  It can ```RAISE``` messages, so you can do ```RAISE NOTICE %, some_val;```